# Difference between bending elasticity and Stretching elasticity in complex solids

Tags: material-science, elasticity

In a solid, elasticity is described by the Young modulus E.

Let us consider a thin sheet of material of thickness h. 
The bending rigidity is usually Eh³.

I wanted to know if they are "abnormal" materials in which the bending rigidity is much smaller than Eh³, for example some polymers or foams...

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes; a [continuous track](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Caterpillar_track_shingle.JPG) (such as a tank track, for example) has a nonzero  effective Young’s modulus but zero bending rigidity. This is true for any sheet containing revolute joints. The 1-D version is a chain. (These aren’t continuous materials, of course, but then neither is a foam, which you mentioned in your question.)